# Why is IPython.display.Image not showing in output?

Tags: python, ipython

I have a cell that looks like this:

```
from IPython.display import Image
i = Image(filename='test.png')
i
print("test")
```

The output is just:

```
test
```

I don't see the image in the output. I checked to see that the file exists (anyway, if it did not exist, you get an error).

Any clues?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

creating the image with

```
i = Image(filename='test.png')
```

only creates the object to display. Objects are displayed by one of two actions:

1. a direct call to `IPython.display.display(obj)`, e.g.

   ```
   from IPython.display import display
   display(i)
   ```
2. the `displayhook`, which automatically displays the *result* of the cell, which is to say putting `i` on the *last line of the cell*. The lone `i` in your example doesn't display because it is not the last thing in the cell. So while this doesn't display the image:

   ```
   i = Image(filename='test.png')
   i
   print("test")
   ```

   This would:

   ```
   i = Image(filename='test.png')
   print("test")
   i
   ```

Comment: I am only getting <IPython.core.display.Image object>

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
Matplot lib expects to show figs outside the command line, for example in the GTK or QT.

Use this: `get_ipython().magic(u'matplotlib inline')`

It will enable inline backend for usage with IPython notebook.

See more [here](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/plotting.html) and [here](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/api/generated/IPython.core.magics.pylab.html).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13978318)

Comment: True, I'll fix that.

Comment: I am getting error of AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'magic'

Comment: Are you in the interactive mode or jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 0):

After looking into the code, I can say, that under Windows, as of IPython 7.1.0, this is only supported with `%matplotlib inline`, which does not work under the interactive IPython shell.

There is extra code in Jupyter. The following example works with

- `jupyter qtconsole`
- `jupyter notebook`
- `jupyter console` in principle, but only via external program, and then for the example the temporary file got deleted

`def test_display():
    import pyx
    c = pyx.canvas.canvas()
    circle = pyx.path.circle(0, 0, 2)
    c.stroke(circle, [pyx.style.linewidth.Thick,pyx.color.rgb.red])
    return c
display(test_display())`