# Unable to display IPython object in ubuntu, but displayed in colab output

Tags: python, image, ubuntu, ipython, display

I have a bunch of images in "test" folder and I have a python code in a file to display those images. Here is the code

```
import torch
from IPython.display import Image, clear_output
import matplotlib
import glob
import PIL
from IPython.display import Image, display
from io import BytesIO

print("hi")
for imageName in glob.glob('test/images/*.jpg'): #assuming JPG
  print("in \n")
  display(Image(filename=imageName)) #displaying successfully in colab
  print("out")
  print("\n")
```

and here is the output when I ran the python file in ubuntu terminal.

[image: Terminal output ss of code]

I have no other tab opened to display image the image. I tried other answers in stack overflow but didn't work. However, the images are visible in colab's output.

Comment: this post may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/52627121/13273054

Comment: @WaveShaper I had gone through that post but it didn't help me. I am able to see images in colab's output but not in ubuntu when I ran it in terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running in a terminal, terminals can only display text.
Thus `display(Image(...))` cannot display your image.

`display` and `Image` are really IPython/Jupyter centric utilities that cannot completely function when using purely Python.

If you want to show images when running in a terminal you will need to use something like [pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html) or [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/images.html) and ask them to open a new window with the image, and depending on how you do it, you may need to close the window for the program to keep executing.

You can also locally run `jupyter notebook` (or, `jupyter lab`) to open a web interface that should support images.